# Image resolution issue while scaling image

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimage, screen-capture

In my iPhone app i have to do image editing. User can add caption on image and then save that image with caption and share that image. First when we choose picture from gallery i have used below method to scale image for my image view:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screenRect.size, NO, 0.0f);
float hfactor = img.size.width / screenRect.size.width;
float vfactor = img.size.height / screenRect.size.height;

float factor = MAX(hfactor, vfactor);

float newWidth = img.size.width / factor;
float newHeight = img.size.height / factor;

float leftOffset = (screenRect.size.width - newWidth) / 2;
float topOffset = (screenRect.size.height - newHeight) / 2;

if (leftOffset>0) {
    mainImgView.frame=CGRectMake(leftOffset+10, screenRect.origin.y, newWidth, newHeight);
}
else if(topOffset>0)
{
    mainImgView.frame=CGRectMake(screenRect.origin.x, topOffset+10, newWidth, newHeight);
}

CGRect newRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, screenRect.size.height);

[img drawInRect:newRect blendMode:kCGBlendModePlusDarker alpha:1];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}

For saving the image with caption i have taken screenshot of view on which both image view and caption label are taken using below code:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImgView.frame.size,NO,0.0f);
 [mainImgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *newImage=[[UIImage alloc]init];
 newImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But by taking screen short , image that get saved has very low resolution and get pixelated when we zoom that image. Is there any way to save image with actual resolution, so that both picture and caption are saved as image?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the reason is in scaleFactor for retina display.Note that in retina devices images have to be twice larger than container's size, that holds it.
Try this:

```
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainImgView.frame.size,NO, [UIScreen     mainScreen].scale);
```